# levenshtein and access database..how to integrate

Tags: ms-access, levenshtein-distance

could anyone help me how to integrate the levenshtein function in an accessdatabase, which I will be query-ing from vb.net later through normal sql statements.

I would like to be able to do a 
SELECT levenshtein(colx, 'myinputword') AS dist FROM table WHERE dist < 3

or something like that...

I know on mysql one can create a custom function and call that afterwards, but I have no clue on how to do this in access.

or is this just not possible in access

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to have custom functions in MS Access (UDF), but it is not possible to use the function outside of Access.